# ValueError: unconverted data remains: 05:37:33.204381, django, datetime

Tags: python, django

Мне надо отфильтровать три дня начиная с текущего, но выходит ошибка `ValueError: unconverted data remains:  05:37:33.204381`

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

now = datetime.today()
print(now) # 2023-01-11 05:37:33.204381
end_date = datetime.strptime(now, '%Y-%m-%d') + timedelta(days=3)
getStatus = Orders.objects.filter(created_at__range=[now, end_date])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исправьте данную строку:

```
end_date = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=3)
```

Храним в переменной end_date текущую дату + 3 дня. Далее используем данную переменную для фильтрации.